# Create folder in for loop and set the folder as the current directory to write/export files to it

Tags: python-3.x

> I'm struggling for the couple hours to find out how I can write the files into a directory created in the `for` loop.

Mainly I do scripting for data manipulation but want to move forward to work with the `os` and `subprocesses` and I'm struggling to do this basic stuff when comes to automation at the OS level ...

> Problem statement: Create a folder in the for loop in a specified path
>   and for each folder created add some work inside, like: files or
>   export pictures or logs.

> Issue I have: folders gets created but the files are getting written to the script path instead the new created folder.

```
import os
import random
import pathlib

path = "/home/sample/folder/"


for i in range(5):


    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, 'train_set' + str(i)))
    print(fd)
    wd=os.getcwd()
    print(wd)

    #tried to use this way but no success ... 
    #os.chdir(wd)
    #os.system ("mkdir "+i)
    #dest_fold = dest_path + dname

    lst = list(df.index.values)
    random.shuffle(lst)

    #with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for lst in range(1, len(df) , 30):
        slc_all = df.iloc[lst : lst + 30]
        print(len(slc_all))
        count = 0
        for j in range(count, len(slc_all)):
            ...
            export_png(p, filename= "file"+str(j)+".png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help.

```
import os
import random
import pathlib

path = "/home/sample/folder/"


for i in range(5):

    dir = os.path.join(path, 'train_set' + str(i))
    os.makedirs(dir)

    lst = list(df.index.values)
    random.shuffle(lst)

    #with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for lst in range(1, len(df) , 30):
        slc_all = df.iloc[lst : lst + 30]
        print(len(slc_all))
        count = 0
        for j in range(count, len(slc_all)):
            ...
            export_png(p, filename= os.path.join(dir, "file"+str(j)+".png"))   #Use Full path to save file.
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution !